android - correct clear candidate suggestions in BaseInputConnection when pressing enter
I am using BaseInputConnection to implement the typing suggestions for a custom text input widget. However backspace/del aren't handled automatically so I implement them in sendKeyEvent() like so:
public class CustomInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection {

    public CustomInputConnection(View view, boolean fullEditor) {
        super(view, fullEditor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int keycode = event.getKeyCode();

        // If this is backspace/del or if the key has a character representation,
        // need to update the underlying Editable (i.e. the local representation of the text
        // being edited).  Some IMEs like Jellybean stock IME and Samsung IME mix in delete
        // KeyPress events instead of calling deleteSurroundingText.
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            Log.i("Foo", "delete < ");
            deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
        } else if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL) {
            Log.i("Foo", "delete >");
            deleteSurroundingText(0, 1);
        } else if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            Log.i("Foo", "enter");

            // None of these works:

            //setComposingText("", 0);

            //beginBatchEdit();
            //finishComposingText();
            //endBatchEdit();

            //CharSequence beforCursorText = getTextBeforeCursor(100, 0);
            //CharSequence afterCursorText = getTextAfterCursor(100, 0);
            //deleteSurroundingText(beforCursorText.length(), afterCursorText.length());

            //deleteSurroundingText(100, 100);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
        Log.i("Foo", "onCommitText: " + text.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean endBatchEdit() {
        String text = getTextBeforeCursor(100, 0).toString();
        Log.i("Foo", "onEditText: " + text);
        return super.endBatchEdit();
    }
}


When typing "hello", then pressing  and typing "abc", I expect to see "abc", but instead it says "helloabc". I haven't been able to get this work.
Here's some sample output:
onEditText: h
onEditText: h
onEditText: he
onEditText: he
onEditText: hel
onEditText: hel
onEditText: hel
onEditText: hell
onEditText: hell
onEditText: hell
onEditText: hello
onEditText: hello
enter
onEditText:
onEditText:
onEditText: helloa
onEditText: helloa
onEditText: helloab
onEditText: helloab
onEditText: helloabx
onEditText: helloabx

Here's how I create the InputConnection:
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        outAttrs.inputType = EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
            | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT;
        outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN
            | EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;
        // fullEditor is false, but we might set this to true for enabling
        // text selection, and copy/paste. Lets see.
        return new CustomInputConnection(this, false);
    }

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this to work?
It's like the IME remembers what has been entered and ignores the will of the input connection.
I want to clear the typing suggestions and reset the state of the BaseInputConnection completely. How can I do that?


Replacing imeOptions setting EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE with EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE fixes the issue.
